# Simple Server/Client with CF Networking cocoa

Tags: cocoa, networking, client, cfnetwork

I've been looking around for something like this for a while, but I can't find anything.
I just want an example of a really really basic server/client with CF networking in cocoa.... there's a lot of stuff out there thats like super convoluted etc - there's got  to be a clean, simple way to just set up a server, have a client send it like a number, say "1", and then return the number recieved +1 or something really rudimentary like that

i just feel like it can't possibly be that hard to send a server a number and have the server relpy with another number..

i've got some experience with c/c++/obj c but i'm not too great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should refer this [CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH1-DontLinkElementID_30). This book is intended for developers who want to use network protocols in their applications. In order to fully understand this book, you should have a good understanding of network programming concepts such as BSD sockets, streams and HTTP protocols. Additionally, you should be familiar Mac OS X programming concepts including run loops.